# application with multiple "accounts", each containing multiple users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, associations

I am trying to build an application with multiple "accounts", each containing multiple users.

I've started with the gem Devise to create user authentication, and I've created Accounts and Preferences MVC's with scaffolding.

The Account model has_one Preferences, and has_many Users
The User model and Preferences model belongs_to my Account model

I've tested these relationships in the console and they seem to work..
What I would like to do, is make sure that when users are logged in, they can only view records associated with their account. From what I've seen, the current_user helper can be used, but I would like to use something like a "current_account". 
1. First question is, is there a resource, Gem, method that can help me to create this current_account variable?
2. Second question would be, what do I need to put in my View for this to work? For instance, if a user wants to update his Preferences associated with his account, how would we call this in the _form partial, would if be something like this?

```
<%= @account.preference.opt_in %>
```

and if they wanted to see all of the users in the account, would it be something like this?

```
<% @customer.user.each do |account| %>
<%= user.email %>
<% end %>
```

Please let me know if I'm overlooking anything major, I've been working on this the last few days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for a multi-tenancy solution. If so, you don't need to come up with your own solution, as there are well established patterns out there.

You can try the [Milia](https://github.com/dsaronin/milia) gem, which fits in nicely with devise.

Comment: Thanks, yes, multi-tenancy is what I'm looking for. I did try the Milia gem but the documentation on how to use it seems incomplete. It's exactly what I'm looking for but can't get it to work so for now I'm going to try it with scopes and see if I can get the funtionality I need.   http://railscasts.com/episodes/388-multitenancy-with-scopes?view=comments

Comment: Is there a newer gem that does multi-tenancy for Rails in 2016?

Comment: @fatuhoku try https://github.com/influitive/apartment theres a free video tutorial at https://gorails.com/episodes/multitenancy-with-apartment.